# How to I get unknown value not shown on venn diagram?

Tags: math, logic, venn-diagram

I just can't figure out how to come up with the value that isn't represented?

[image]

I just can't figure out how I'm supposed to arrive at the answer here. Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question would be better suited to [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

We will assume people only identified as men or women.  Then:

```
Number ppl who agree = Number of men who agree + Number of women who agree.
```

You know two of these values from the diagram so you can calculate the third.